# Elasticsearch Index document count to query performance - is it linear?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm being asked to estimate the query throughput decrease for an imaginary ES index of 1B documents by "extrapolating from" the actual index we have of 10M docs.

Keeping things very simple - assume a 3-node Elasticsearch cluster with one index of 10 million static documents (no further insertions or deletions of documents).  Average query performance is 100 queries per second.

Now, with the same cluster, you have one index of 1 billion static documents (assume all documents are approx. the same size).  **If all things assumed linear**, you'd be looking at 1 query per second, as 1B is 100x 10M.  But I can't help but think that it can't be straight linear like that b/c certainly searching against an index of 100 docs is not going to be 10x slower than querying against 1000 docs... so maybe the answer is that it's really logarithmic to an extent?

Any guidance here would be very helpful as at this point, all I would know to do is take our current QPS rate and multiply it by 100, which would put our QPS rate in pretty bad spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working with Elasticsearch for long enough to really, truly, deeply understand where this question is coming from, but the answer you'll stumble across time and time again is honestly true: you just have to try it and see.

The reality is that you're correct. Almost certainly, your real-world performance against more documents will not scale linearly. In reality, query performance depends on a lot of factors, including (but surely not limited to):

1. Query overhead, which will remain more or less constant across variable document counts (or *at most* scale with the number of indexes you're hitting).
2. Index layout, assuming your billion documents don't have a linearly scaled number of *unique* terms, the actual index won't scale in size and complexity  with each extra document.
3. Caching, which obviously just behaves differently under all sorts of other variables.

Elasticsearch is internally doing a lot more than visiting each document, calculating a score or aggregations, then going to the next, and the next, and eventually returning results. It's using many tools to help limit the amount of effort it has to do, and these make it incredibly difficult to reliably predict performance. My billion documents will likely perform very differently from yours, even if they're roughly the same size.

The best option I can suggest is to try and mock out fake data--perhaps using an online generator, or procedurally creating some based on statistics you can find in your limited set--and testing performance with that. It might not be perfect, but that will give you a much more realistic answer than anyone here could.